# .NET versioning - no error

Tags: vb.net

I have read that versioning can be a problem if a project is split into multiple DLLs.  I am trying to introduce a versioning problem to understand what it means.  I have two simple projects i.e. a windows forms application and a class library.  Here is the form:

```
Imports ClassLibrary1

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim c1 As Class1 = New class1
        c1.TEST()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the class library:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub TEST()
        MsgBox("TEST1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please see the version number of the windows form app below:

[image]

Please see the version of the class library below:

[image]

When I build the project I get an executable and a DLL as expected.  I have followed these steps in an attempt to introduce a versioning problem:

```
 1) Build the project
 2) Go to the bin folder and create a copy of debug/WindowsApplication1.exe 
 3) Go into the DLL properties and change the DLL version in Visual Studio
 4) Rebuild the project
 5) Overwrite the .EXE in the BIN folder (debug/WindowsApplication1.exe) with the .EXE copied in step 2
 6) Launch the .EXE in the bin folder
```

I thought I would see an error at step five as an old version of the .exe is using the new DLL.  However, the program runs as expected.  What am I missing? I realise this is a basic question.  I have Googled it this afternoon.

Comment: You probably copied the wrong EXE.  Step 5 should fail, the .vshost.exe can't be overwritten while the project is loaded.  Your repro steps certainly are not detailed enough, starting with describing a "bin" folder that doesn't contain any EXE.

Comment: what about configuration manager and your compile dependency? You have to check that also when you work at VS solution with multiple dlls and exe's

Comment: @Hans Passant,thanks.  I have edited the repro to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The GUID is the more important part.  Open up your vbproj file (or csproj file for future readers) and see how the .EXE vbproj references the .DLL project.

The numbers (on the version) which you are changing .... are kinda like friendly FYI's.

If the GUID matches and there are not breaking changes, your old exe can use the new dll and vice versa.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyDll\MyDll.csproj">
      <Project>{33333333-3333-3333-3333-33333333333}</Project>
      <Name>MyDll</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

EDIT:

You may want to try:

Changing the signature of your method.

```
Public Sub TEST(s as String)
    MsgBox("TEST1")
End Sub
```

Or change the name (which is the same as removing it)

```
Public Sub TEST1()
    MsgBox("TEST1 Msg")
End Sub
```

Or change the GUID of the "DLL" project in the project properties (that you already know about from your screen shot above)

Comment: Thanks.  Where are the references stored at runtime?

Comment: When you build the DLL, they are "compiled into" the dll or exe.

Comment: Thanks +1.i will try your suggestions tomorrow and then come back to the post to mark the answer.